# How can I check the installed version of dotnet core using Java

Tags: java

I am writing a java application where I need to check what is the installed version of `dotnet` core on the host machine. I need to first check whether my host machine is `windows` or `Linux` and then check the `dotnet` version. Is there a simpler way to do it in Java?

Answer (score 3):

with

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = runtime.exec("dotnet --version");
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

you will get the version of your installed dotnet version.

Comment: Since java 5, class [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is preferred over class `Runtime`. Method `inheritIO()` in class `ProcessBuilder` saves you from explicitly creating a "reader" object for the output of the created process.